# Append line break to command output

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a single-line command that does a curl request to check server status and then output the result to a log file. But the problem is the returned result has no line break and so the log file messes up when the command writes to the log file the next time around.

```
curl -s "http://myserver.com/api?param=1&param=2" | sudo tee -a /var/log/myserver.log
```

I like to keep this to a single-line command. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `echo`, it will automatically append a newline:

```
echo "`curl -s "http://myserver.com/api?param=1&param=2"`" | sudo tee -a /var/log/myserver.log
```

Alternatively, you could try the `-w` option, but I found that it somehow prints funny characters to the console (but not to the file, luckily):

```
curl -s "http://myserver.com/api?param=1&param=2" -w "\n" | sudo tee -a /var/log/myserver.log
```

Comment: I tried both, but they didn't work. Interestingly, the first one actually removes all line breaks from the result. Could it be due to the use of ` in the command? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed the output or `curl` would not contain line breaks. I added double quotes around the `\`` invocation, so that should do. The second option should work fine, though, as it only instructs curl to output a newline additionally (see `man curl`).

Comment: After adding the double quotes around the ` it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Simplest is just to append a newline using `echo`

```
curl -s "http://myserver.com/api?param=1&param=2" | sudo tee -a /var/log/myserver.log && echo "" >> /var/log/myserver.log
```

Comment: Hmmm...when I tried this on my local machine, it works fine. But when used in the server, it says, "bash: /var/log/myserver.log: Permission denied". Adding sudo before echo didn't work either.

Comment: But it's not using sudo to echo into your logfile, so at least it'll need to be `... && echo | sudo tee -a ...` unless sudo isn't needed?

Comment: try `(curl -s "http://www.nexon.org.uk" && echo "") | sudo tee -a ...`

Answer (score 5):

I use `awk 1` for that (where `1` is just something that evaluates to true):

```
$ printf a|awk 1
a
$ printf a\\n|awk 1
a
$
```

It should work with gawk, BWK awk / nawk (that comes with OS X), and mawk (that comes with Debian). `sed -n p` works with OS X's sed but not with GNU sed.

A Bash-only alternative:

```
printf %s\\n "$(cat)"
```

Note that `$()` removes all linefeeds from the end, so for example `echo $'a\n\n'|printf %s\\n "$(cat)"` only prints one linefeed.

You could also replace `printf %s\\n` with `echo`, but for example `x=-nene;echo "$x"` doesn't print anything in Bash (unless `xpg_echo` and POSIX mode are enabled).

Answer (score 5):

Add the `-w "\n"` switch or put

```
-w "\n"
```

into your `~/.curlrc`

Answer (score 1):

Other syntax using echo:

```
commands... | { cat; echo; } | ...
```